# How to Promisify this recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Below is a simple recursive function that takes in a length, and decrements it using `setTimeout`.  Once the length is `<=` 0, it's done.

How can I write this function (in pure JavaScript) so that I can use it like so:

`animate(999).then(...)`

```js
const animate = length => {
  console.log(length)
  length -= 10
  if (length <= 0) {
    length = 0
    return
  }
  setTimeout(() => {animate(length)}, 10)
}

animate(999)
```

**Update:**

This is what I've tried.  The problem I'm having is that it seems `resolve` is either not being called, or is being called on a different promise.

```js
const animate = length => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(length)
    length -= 10
    if (length <= 0) {
      length = 0
      resolve(true)
      return // without this the function runs forever
    }
    setTimeout(() => {animate(length)}, 10)
  })
}

animate(999).then(result => console.log(result))
```

** Working Update (but don't understand it) **

```js
const animate = length => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(length)
    length -= 10
    if (length <= 0) {
      length = 0
      return resolve(true)
    }
    setTimeout(() => {resolve(animate(length))}, 10)
  })
}

animate(999).then(result => console.log(result))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setTimeout(() => {animate(length)}, 10)` will not work, this might call the `animate` function again but never resolve the promise created in the outermost invocation (this is what your "working update" fixes - it resolves the outer promise with the promise from the recursive call, which will cause them to fulfill with the same result).

Instead of messing around with callbacks that much, [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) the asynchronous primitive that you are using, `setTimeout`:

```
function wait(t) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, t);
    });
}
```

and then use that in your animation function to always return a promise:

```
const animate = length => {
  console.log(length)
  length -= 10
  if (length <= 0) {
    length = 0
    return Promise.resolve()
  }
  return wait(10).then(() => {
    return animate(length)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A new `Promise` and consequently its `resolve` and `reject` is being generated every time, because you are returning a new `Promise` on every `setTimeout` function call and only resolving the latest one (the one inside the `if (length <= 0)`).

If you had placed the `Promise((resolve, reject)` over the function it would have worked fine.

Either that or you carry the `resolve, reject` with you.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, you *can* do this. You **shouldn't** though. The code is beyond unmaintainable.

```js
const animate = (length, resolve) => {
  var promise;
  
  if (!resolve) {
    promise = new Promise((newResolve) => {
      resolve = newResolve;
    });
  }
  
  console.log(length);
  length -= 10;
  
  if (length <= 0) {
    length = 0;
    resolve(true);
    return promise;
  }
  
  setTimeout(() => {animate(length, resolve)}, 10);
  
  return promise;
}

animate(999).then(result => console.log(result))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent job for `async`/`await`:

```js
let wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const animate = async length => {
  for (; length > 0; length -= 10) {
    console.log(length);
    await wait(10);
  }
  return 0;
}

animate(999).then(() => console.log("Done!"));
```